# filter a list of object by its list field

Tags: java, lambda, collections, java-8, java-stream

There are two plain objects for Student and Course like this:

```
public class Student {
    List<Course> courses;
    ...
}
public class Course {
    String name;
    ...
}
```

If we have a `list` of `Students`, how can we filter some of students by the name of their courses?

- first I try `flatMap` to answer this question, but it returns course
  objects instead student objects.
- then I use `allMatch` (following codes).
  however it returns Student list but the `List` always is empty. What is the
  problem?

```java
List<Student> studentList;
List<Student> AlgorithmsCourserStudentList = studentList.stream().
    filter(a -> a.stream().allMatch(c -> c.getCourseName.equal("Algorithms"))).
    collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need `anyMatch`:

```
List<Student> studentList;
List<Student> algorithmsCourseStudentList = 
    studentList.stream()
               .filter(a -> a.getCourses()
                             .stream()
                             .anyMatch(c -> c.getCourseName().equals("Algorithms")))
               .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

- `allMatch` will only give you `Student`s that all their `Course`s are named `"Algorithms"`.
- `anyMatch` will give you all `Student`s that have at least one `Course` named `"Algorithms"`.

Answer (score 3):

For each student get the courses and find if there is any match in the student's courses on the name of the course.

Course.java:

```
public class Course {
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Student.java:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Student {
    private List<Course> courses;

    public List<Course> getCourses() {
        return courses;
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();

        List<Student> algorithmsStudents = students.stream()
                .filter(s -> s.getCourses().stream().anyMatch(c -> c.getName().equals("Algorithms")))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

*edit:*

```
List<Student> AlgorithmsCourserStudentList = studentList.stream().
    filter(a -> a.stream().allMatch(c -> c.getCourseName.equal("Algorithms"))).
    collect(Collectors.toList());
```

- Your code here won't compile, in the filter 'a' is a student, which is does not have a stream() method.
- You can't use flatMap() to convert the student's list of courses to a stream because then you can't collect the students further on
- `allMatch` yields `true` if all elements in the list match the predicate, `false` if there is a single element not matching. So if the code would be correct you'd be testing if all the student's courses have the name 'Algorithms', but you want to test if there is a single element that matches the condition. Note that `allMatch` and `anyMatch` *do not* return lists, they return a `boolean` which is why you can use them in the filter.

Comment: You're posting an answer 10 minutes after one has already been posted, and of lower quality than the previous answer since yours is little more than a code dump and his offers explanation.

Comment: Nope, the other answer was incorrect while I was answering this one. It was edited while I was typing this.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Eran. Also you can use `method references` in `filter` as following:

```
students.stream()
            .filter(s -> s.getCourses().stream()
                    .map(Course::getName)
                    .anyMatch("Algorithms"::equals)
            ).collect(Collectors.toList());
```